# Rspec features macro wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I created a macro for my create_post_spec.rb
rails v-5.2
ruby  v-2.5.1
capybara v-3.2'

my macro

#### spec/support/features/session.rb

```
module Features

  def sign_in(user)
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_on "Log in"
  end
  
end
```

then include in my rails_helper

```
Rspec.confifure do |config|
 config.include Feature, type: feature
end
```

in my

#### spec/feature/create_post_spec.rb

```
require "rails_helper"
```

RSpec.describe "Create post" do

```
let(:user){ User.create(email: "example@mail.com", password: "password",
                     password_confirmation: "password")} 

  scenario "successfuly creating post" do    
    sign_in user
    visit root_path
    click_on "Create post"
    fill_in "Title", with: "Awesome title"
    fill_in "Body", with: "My rspec test"
    click_on "Publish"
    expect(page).to have_current_path root_path
  end

  scenario "unsuccessful creating post" do
    sign_in user
    visit root_path
    click_on "Create post"
    fill_in "Title", with: "Awesome title"
    fill_in "Body", with: ""
    click_on "Publish"
    expect(page).to have_css ".error"  
  end

  scenario "non-logged in user cant create post" do
  
  end

end
```

i get an undefined method sign_in,
But if i use "feature" in my block

```
RSpec.feature "Create post....." do
```

it works

i wonder why it won't work if i use "describe"

```
RSpec.describe "Create post....." do
```

Comment: Doesn't it fail on `RSpec.confifure`?

Comment: `config.include Feature, type: :feature`

Comment: I already add that in my rails_helper.  It's only only if my spec is like this RSpec.feature but not in RSpec.describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `RSpec.feature` and `Rspec.describe` is that `RSpec.feature` adds `type: :feature` and `capybara_feature: true` metadata to the block. The important thing there is the `type: :feature` metadata since it's what you're using to trigger the include of your module. You can use `describe` by adding your own metadata

```
RSpec.describe "Create post", type: :feature do
  ...
end
```

or you can have RSpec automatically add the type based on the directory the spec file is in by changing the file directory to `spec/features/xxx.rb` (note the plural `features`) and ensuring

```
RSpec.configure.do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

is enabled in your rails_helper - see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure

Comment: RSpec.describe "Create post", type: :feature do
  ...
end

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it's working now,  It works on me before just by adding this in my Rails.config ` RSpec.configure do |config|   config.include Features, type: :feature end`